# Какую несет значимость параметр this при создании объектов в qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Например, при создании менеджера горизонтальной компановки, зачем и почему там именно this:

```
QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout(this);
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhboxlayout.html#details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном контексте это означает, что родителем этого горизонтального layout'а будет текущий виджет.

`this` - это указатель на конкретный объект класса (который хранит адрес этого объекта). Допустим, есть класс красных машин, а this может указывать на конкретную красную машину - экземпляр класса красных машин.

Comment: Добавлю, что родительство в Qt означает, что родительский объект при вызове деструктора сам освободит память всех потомков, т.е. вам не надо вызывать delete.